# set cell or row background color in a google spreadsheet using google_drive gem on ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, spreadsheet, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I'm trying to set a background color for a cell and a row and am using the 'google_drive' gem.
It looks like that the 'spreadsheet' gem does have this option

```
format = Spreadsheet::Format.new :color=> :blue, :pattern_fg_color => :yellow, :pattern => 1
```

if the 'google_drive' gem also has this option, please let me know!

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to set the background color by setting `:color => :blue`. Instead, set `:pattern_bg_color => :blue`.

All options:
`:bottom_color, :top_color, :left_color, :right_color, :pattern_fg_color, :pattern_bg_color, :diagonal_color`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you specify how do you intend to use it ?